# Submit form on prop value changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and trying to modify this application: https://github.com/nice-table/bitmex-scaled-orders

My goal is, say the prop "instrumentData" found in "src/modules/orders/OrderForm.js" has "instrumentData.lastprice" value changing to a specific value in real-time in the backend. I want to submit the form on that page if the value reaches a specific value. In other words, I want to keep monitoring that prop untill it hits a number and it will submit the form upon that. Is that doable through states? I tried to research it but given I am new to React I am a bit lost as to what code to use and where exactly to add it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Autosubmitting is simple

It's simple to run some action on data change. React components are data driven - autoupdating. You can just insert a function 'into data flow'.

Your data source is in `DataContext` then you should use `<DataContext.Consumer />` to get data 'stream' - stream because it's frequently updated using socket connection.

```
<DataContext.Consumer>
  { (data, submitForm, isSubmitting) => {

    console.log("context data", data );
    // extract data from `data` object
    // const someData = data.someProperty;
    // if( someData > 12345 ) {
    //   if( !isSubmitting ) {
    //     submitForm() 
    //   }
    //   return "Limit reached"
    // }
    // return null

  }}
</ DataContext.Consumer>
```

This snippet can be placed almost anywhere after this code:

```
  render={({
    values,
    errors,
    touched,
    setFieldValue,
    submitForm,
    isSubmitting,
    isValid,
    validateForm
  }) => (
    <React.Fragment>
       // place it here
```

... and of course before end of this fragment (`</ React.Fragment>`).

You can pass and use almost all functions defined in this component (file), f.e. `setFieldValue("priceUpper",` to update form value before submitting.

### Autosubmitting is NOT so simple

Problem is not trivial. You should create a component with internal logic to:

- set limit (render input, onChange handler, useState) instead of hardcoded value
- block(or not? checkbox?) autosubmitting in a loop (formik will submit but later it will clear `isSubmitting` flag - our component will autosubmit again)
- render context consumer inside - optimize rerenderings
- etc.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My goal is not to change form values. All I want to do is "submit" the form (just as if I clicked the submit button). So my question is in this file (https://github.com/nice-table/bitmex-scaled-orders/blob/master/src/modules/orders/OrderForm.js) I want to make it check in real-time for the "instrumentData.lastprice" and whenever instrumentData.lastprice>=999  I want it to submit the form in that page. That's it. Would appreciate it if you can advise what code snippet to use and where to insert it. Thanks!

Comment: answer is exactly this component related, explore data for exact value you need

Comment: Sorry I am still not sure. So you mean I can put it anywhere in the file to pull the stream, and inside it I do submitForm(); ?
Can you elaborate more please

Answer (score -1):

React has a really good write up on forms and handling onChange() which is an event that can fire when a field is changed  https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html.

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  submit = () => {
      // submit form
      // eg axios.post(URL, {
      //   value: this.state.value
      // })
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    if (this.state.value == 10) {
       this.submit()
    }
  }

    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I see the github repo is using hooks in lieu of component classes.
You can read about hooks here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html.
onChange can still call handle change and instead of `this.state` you may be using `useState`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The value I want to listen to is not a form field, it is just a prop passed to the OrderForm. I tried to implement this but I am a bit lost in this code given I am new to React. Where exactly should I add the code and what code should I add? Assuming I want to listen to changes on "instrumentData.lastprice" and imitate submitting the form on that page if(instrumentData.lastprice >= 999").